# How do i update available versions for operating system types in virt-manager

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, linux-kvm, qemu, virt-manager

How do i update available versions for operating system types in virt-manager?

For example for Ubuntu, only up to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in the menu but I'm installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Installation still works fine choosing Ubuntu 14. I'm just curious how to update the available versions in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`virt-manager` gets its list of operating systems from `libosinfo`.

The path to the database is `/usr/share/libosinfo/db/oses`.

On Ubuntu, the package that provides this database is [`libosinfo-1.0-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libosinfo-1.0-0&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

You have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr, which means that you can manually install the [updated Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus package `libosinfo-1.0-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libosinfo-1.0-0) without a dependency conflict.

In Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak, the [dependencies changed](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libosinfo-1.0-0).  You can still install `libosinfo-1.0-0`, but first, you must install the new package [`libosinfo-db`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libosinfo-db).  This is the only difference, if you choose to pull `libosinfo-1.0-0` from the Ubuntu 16.10 repo.

Alternatively, you can build [`libosinfo` from source](https://fedorahosted.org/releases/l/i/libosinfo/).

Practically, you do not need to update this database any time soon because in `virt-manager`, they're mainly for recommending resource allocations and virtual hardware, all of which you can configure manually if desired.